# How to check if the same ID get the same grade for different subjects?

Tags: php, mysql

```
ID    | Subject | Grade

12113   BM         A     
12113   BI         A    
12113   MM         A    
12113   SJ         A    
12113   GE         B    
12113   SV         A    
12113   PJ         A    
12112   BM         A     
12112   BI         A    
12112   MM         A    
12112   SJ         A    
12112   GE         A    
12112   SV         A    
12112   PJ         A
```

Hie all, above are the sample table of showing the studentID with multiple subject takens. I couldnt figure out how to use mysql query to check if the same studentID has score A for all subjects.

was trying to use `HAVING MAX(Grade) = 'A'` but doesnt help. any advice?

Comment: There isn't a query that could do that in this construction that i know of. You'd have to pull the data and do it with arrays in php.

Comment: @MarshallHouse Actually, there are many ways of doing this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID, 
case when count(ID) = sum(case when Grade = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) then 'YES' else 'NO' end as IsAllAGrade
from yourTable
group by ID
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return all students that have `A` in all subjects:

```
select distinct id from t t1
where not exists (
  select * from t t2
  where t1.id = t2.id and grade != 'A')
```

If you want to check for a particular student just add a `where` clause. By the way... can a student have more than one result for a given subject? (Twice the same subject but with different grade)

You can check the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8313/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  from table t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id 
  and t2.grade <> t1.grade)
```

Without assumptions ('suppose all ID's have 7 courses'), works always, is what [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/pt/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) was made for.

#### If you want only ID's which get all A's

... just add a where clause (or change the existing one):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  from table t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id 
  and t2.grade <> 'A')
```

Comment: @MGA Actually this will also match where students have 'B's for all subjects.

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yes, that is what the title of his question asked. If he wants all A's, the query just becomes easier. This is the generic answer which intends to help future viewers too.

Comment: Good point! It is a bit ambiguous as the text of the post explicitly asks for `A`.

Comment: @MostyMostacho: I added it to my answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (ordering ascending and only give the first value A in your case)

```
SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE `ID` = '12112' AND `Subject` = 'MM' ORDER BY `Grade` ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```